# Phonegap, call from Android to Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, webview, phonegap-plugins

I know that question has been made a million times here, but none of the answers seems to fit my needs.

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` that receive data from other apps, so **code execution is started at Android native code** always.

I saw that `webView.sendJavascript` is deprecated, but I don't have Cordova `webview` available on the `BroadcastReceiver`.

I noticed that you would do something like that:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:console.log('hello from wear: " + mStopsNumber + "');");
```

But again I can't access `cordova`, `webview` objects from a `BroadcastReceiver`

I don't understand how there are so many questions that ask for something similar and everybody answer about how to build a Cordova Plugin. I know how to build my custom Cordova Plugin, but as far as I understand, Cordova Plugin is initiated at JS code with `codova.exec(whatever` and this is not my scenario.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Make your `BroadcastReceiver` a non-`static` inner class of your `CordovaPlugin`. You can now access fields of your `CordovaPlugin` inside of the `BoradcastReceiver`. So you need to store the `CordovaWebView` passed in `initialize` in a field in order to access it.

---

Edit: 
In order to use your `BroadcastReceiver` you either have to register it through code, because the Android Manifest would require an instance of your `CordovaPlugin` to instantiate it, which it can't have.

Or you go a different way and instead of making you `BroadcastReceiver` an inner class you save the `CordovaWebView` in a static context, so you can reach it from anywhere.

Note: You get this error because a non-`static` inner class has an implicit constructor parameter: It's parent object.

Comment: Nice! But when I do that I get an BroadcastReceiver: can't instantiate class; no empty constructor :(